# Android Horizontal Dynamic List View

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to develop an app which is similar to e-book apps. The thing I want to do is having multiple horizontal views according to my data and listing them in a vertical view. Also, I have a view having image and title fields. I want to repeat this view inside of every horizontal view. Both horizontal view number and content of horizontal views should be dynamic. I checked it online there are some components for horizontal views but don't know which is the most useful one. What is the best way to implement this in my project?

Comment: I think ViewPager would work for this requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new view in android called Recycler View (perhaps you have heard about it) . It's a reimplementation of the list-view in android with lots of new features. In Recycler view, you can easily make a horizontal list view. I have found a tutorial for you on the net, The source code is included in the tutorial .

http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html